# How to make a full with custom page in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have created a custom page. But i dont want left and right sidebar in my page but these sidebar are coming.

Please check link : http://darlingdazzles.com/darlingdazzles/en/product-registration

How we can make a full width page without sidebar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure full width page or remove one or both sidebar in:

Preferences/Themes and in current Theme you can click in Advanced Settings and choose per page where you want or don´t want sidebars.